# How do I ping6 VM player?

Tags: ipv6, ping

I need to ping6 VM player(Ubuntu).In VM player, On

> sudo ifconfig

I see

> inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe73:e5f6/64

On trying ping6 from host(Ubuntu)

> ping6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe73:e5f6/64

It shows

> unknown host

How do I successfully ping6 my VM player?

Comment: How is the VM's network adapter configured? NAT? Host-Only? Bridged?

Comment: VM's network adaptor is configured as NAT.